# How to retrieve multiple pieces of data from Firebase and append it to different <div> that do the same thing?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I'm making a page to display data inputted from a form to append to another page using Firebase. I've basically got it setup so there's a form that saves the message using a function and queries it to Firebase, which I then use on another page for display. I've made 1 card so far, and it works fine, but whenever I append data again on the form, it just sticks together side by side then making a new card container. Here are some images:

[image]

Which then turns out to look like this when I fill out the form again:
[image]

As you can see, it turns from "Random UHC" (which is the first event in the Firebase) to "Random UHCRandom Event". I've been trying to set it up so it makes an entire new card-container separately instead of just using the same card. Here's some code as well:
Form that queries data inside Firebase

```
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref().child('messages');

// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

// Submit form
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get values
  var name = getInputVal('name');
  var company = getInputVal('eventTitle');
  var email = getInputVal('date');
  var phone = getInputVal('time');
  var message = getInputVal('message');

  // Save message
  saveMessage(name, company, email, phone, message);

  // Show alert
  document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';

  // Hide alert after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
  },3000);

  // Clear form
  document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();
}

// Function to get get form values
function getInputVal(id){
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

// Save message to firebase
function saveMessage(name, eventTitle, date, time, message){
  var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
  newMessageRef.set({
    name: name,
    eventTitle:eventTitle,
    date:date,
    time:time,
    message:message
  });
}
```

How I output it on the new page:

```
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    
    var name = snap.child("name").val();
    var eventTitle = snap.child("eventTitle").val();
    
    $("#eventTitle").append(eventTitle);

});
```

HTML of the page displaying data:

```
    <div class="card-main">
      <div class="card-head">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" class="card-logo">
        <div class="product-detail">
          <h2>Upcoming Events</h2> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body-1">
        <div class="product-desc">
          <span class="product-title">
                <b><p id = eventTitle style="width:18%; float: left;"></p></b>
                  <span class="badge">
                    New
                  </span>
                  <span class="product-caption">
                    <b>July 5th, 2020 - 
                    5:30 PM EST</b>
                  </span>
          </span>
```

The id element eventTitle is the only thing that is showing on the page right now. Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PLEASE NOTE:** This answer came from [Episode #9 Of The Net Ninjas Firebase Tutorial](https://youtu.be/kIVg_yTiO3Q), To make it faster I think the specifics you are looking for start somewhere between the 8 and 10-minute mark. I would definitely recommend you to go watch his video as he makes everything very clear and does a good job of explaining. That would be my best answer but I tried to explain the most basic form of how to do this below.

As a general rule of thumb, you need to make sure to have your client-side javascript create a new element for every "entry" or card in your database. You would do this by implementing an operation like this which populated a new card for every doc or document in your database.

```
data.forEach(doc => {

})
```

And then for each doc, inside your Javascript, write the template for the HTML and then pass in firebase data or variables using. Example below.

```
data.forEach(doc => {
    // This is simply fetching your doc data and passing that into a constant
    const card = doc.data(); 
    const div = '
        // Put Your HTML used for making the template of the card in here
        // Pass in data to be populated on your card like in the example displayed below   
        <b><p style="width:18%; float: left;">${card.EventTitle}</p></b>
    ';
    html += div
});
eventCards.innerHTML = html;
```

This system should be able to achieve what you are looking for. I might not have explained it the best but if something doesn't work or you have further questions you can reference the before mentioned video or comment. If anyone has a way of improving this answer please let me know!